# Making unique reproducible ids based on strings (for mongoose model)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

I pull data (a list of properties) from a city's website and it contains info like address, property owner, and longitude and latitude.

I need to make a unique id out of this and the properties will be stored in a database. The id needs to be reproducible because I will be checking occasionally to see if there are new properties so the only way to cross compare is by being able to make the id on the spot.

Is this a common problem to run into when pulling data and checking if there is anything new? I am using mongoose as the database and I am not sure if a non relational database is the best solution for my problem but I know I can make it work.

The current plan is to just combine longitude and latitude and call that the unique id. The city's data unfortunately doesn't have any unchanging unique id so I have to hack something together for comparing their data to what I have saved in the database.

Any ideas on what a better less hacky method is? Does mongoose have a different way to deal with this?

Comment: As long as coordinate resolution is accurate enough then it sounds like a plan. It's also worth noting that there are valid cases where street names and numbers "could" change for what is essentially the same address. It all depends on you needs. One caveat though is consideration for storage using geospatial queries. See [Duplicate key error with mongodb 2dsphere unique index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17829641/duplicate-key-error-with-mongodb-2dsphere-unique-index) for more details.

Comment: Meaning that all of the coordinates are going to be unique? That is a good point, it would mess everything up if they were the same. Also if any information other than longitude and latitude change then I think those entries will be ignored completely by my current set up which is a problem since things could certainly change, thanks for the tips!

Comment: Take a look at [geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash).